# Wroom 32 can't be recognized by Arduino 1.8.9 on a ubuntu 19.04 computer

Tags: esp32, ubuntu

I started by plugging my Wroom 32 into my Kubuntu desktop. I checked my /dev before and after, and found no changes. After opening Arduino IDE, I only found my other Arduino, the Arduino Due, in the port list. I already installed the ESP 32 board. What's wrong?

Comment: use `lsusb` and `dmesg` to determine what is happening ... i.e. run `lsusb`, plug the WROOM32 in, run `lsusb` again - anything new detected? run `dmesg` - check the output for errors regarding the new device

Comment: wroom32 has USB?

Comment: @Juraj - not the wroom32 itself. I have a "DOIT" ESP32 dev kit - the ESP32 module on it is a WROOM32 - perhaps the OP has a similar dev kit